# Enable and disable button without page load

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with a dropdown box, login button, and logout button. My requirement is to insert date and time when user click on the login or logout button after username selection from dropdown. Also, when user clicks on login button, it has to enable by changing the background color without page load. Same functionality required for logout option also.

Now, I can select the user's name from the dropdown which is coming from database. I stucked on the insertion part which i need without page load.

I need to insert data without page load once click on the login button.

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once "database.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
if (str=="") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$sql_user="SELECT * FROM users";
$result_user=mysql_query($sql_user);

?>
<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)" style="width: 210px;height: 36px; font-size:17px;">
<option style="height:30px;" value="">Select a person:</option>
<?php while($row_user=mysql_fetch_array($result_user)){?><option style="height:30px;" value="<?php echo $row_user['id'];?>"><?php echo $row_user['username'];?></option><?php }?>

</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**getuser.php**

```
<style>
button{
width: 100px;
height: 38px;
background:white;
color:black;
}
</style>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

include_once "database.php";

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$q'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$entry=$row['entry'];
?>
<form method="post" name="">
<table>
<tr><td>
<button id="btnSave" <?php if($entry=='0'){?> style=" background:#6DAAD4;"<?php }?>> Login</button>
 </td><td>
 <button <?php if($entry=='1'){?> style=" background:#6DAAD4;"<?php }?>> Logout</button>
 </td></tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: Anyone, please help me to figure out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you getuser.php remove form tag and add function 'insertDateTime()' to buttons click event like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
           <button id="btnSave" onclick="insertDateTime(this,'<?php echo $q;?>');"> Login</button>
       </td>
       <td>
           <button id="btnSave" onclick="insertDateTime(this,'<?php echo $q;?>')"> Logout</button>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Add one function to your index.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </script> //better to download and us locally 

<script>
function insertDateTime(obj, id)
{
    $("[id^='"+obj.id+"']").css('background', '#FFFFFF');
    $(obj).css('background', '#6DAAD4');

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var params = "id="+id;

    xmlhttp.open("POST","insertdate.php",true);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }        
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
</script>
```

and write your code in insertdate.php to insert date and time in database. You can get your id using $_POST['id']; in  insertdate.php.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will test your code and let you know.

Comment: Hi, how to pass the "$q" variable(user id from the dropdown) to the insertdate.php file

Comment: I edited code to send id in inserdate.php. I had use POST method you can use GET as in your showUser function if you wish. But better to use POST method.

Comment: Hi, need one more help from you. By default background color for the two buttons will be white. When user clicks on login button, it has to enable by changing the background color to blue for the button without page load. And when user clicks on logout button, logout button need to enable by changing the background color to blue and login button needs to disable by changing color to white without page load.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. I tested the code. Now, by default white color is coming, but background color is not changing.

Comment: It's showing Uncaught Reference error: $ is not defined on inspect element

Comment: Sorry @user2372469 but is jquery code. $("[id^='"+obj.id+"']").css('background', '#FFFFFF'); $(obj).css('background', '#6DAAD4'); To use this, you need to include min required jquery in your code. Otherwise you need to do same in javascript. You can use this http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: Hi, i included <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> in index.php file. Now, I'm getting error like Uncaught Reference error: obj is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Bind onclick = "func()" in button

inside func method, change the color this way :

document.getElementById("formID").style.backgroundColor="lightblue";